# How Topological Sort Works With DFS For The Below Graph

Tags: depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

```
5
^
|
3
^
|
1->2->4
```

For the above graph one of the topological sorts should be 1,3,2,5,4

But if I apply DFS algo(with temp stack) for topological sorting:

- Start at 1.
- Adjacent vertices are 3,2
- Take 3 as next vertex
- Adjacent vertex of 3 is 5
- No adjacent for 5.
- Add 5 into the temp stack.
- Get back to 3 & add 3 to temp stack.
- Take 2 as next vertex
- Adjacent vertex of 2 is 4.
- No adjacent for 4.
- Add 4 to temp stack.
- Get back to 2 & add 2 to temp stack.
- Get back to 1 & add 1 to temp stack.

If I print the temp stack it would show 1,2,4,3,5.

What am I missing here? Please help me with the correct steps for better understanding this particular scenario.

Comment: Most graphs don't have a unique topological sort.  Here both `1,3,2,5,4` and `1,2,4,3,5` seem valid results to me.  I'm not saying that your pseudo-code is correct, just that I don't share your puzzlement.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant to write *I'm not saying that your pseudo-code is incorrect*.

Comment: But my pseudo code results 1,2,4,3,5 which is not valid. Second & third element in the sort should be either 2,3 or 3,2 as they are on the same level.

Comment: That's not my understanding of topological sort; it's merely required that each vertex be listed before any of its children.  As I wrote, I don't know if your pseudo-code is a correct implementation of DFS but the output is a valid topological sort.

Comment: Now I have understood. Thanks.